# Sum of all elements of a list in C

Tags: c, list, sum, double, nodes

I need to get the sum of a list that only contains doubles.
For some reason that doesn't work, though:

```
double sum(DoubleList* list) {
    DoubleNode *next = NULL;  
    double sum = 0;
    for (DoubleNode *n = list->first; n != NULL; n = next) {
        sum += n->value;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: `next` is `NULL` on the second iteration.

Comment: Can you provide the definition of DoubleList?

Comment: You probably mean something like: `for (DoubleNode *n = list->first; n != NULL; n = n->next) {` (notice the`n = n->next`).

Comment: may be you missed `next = n->next`

Comment: ` typedef struct DoubleList {
    DoubleNode* first;
    DoubleNode* last;
   } DoubleList;`

Comment: Oh yes! The n->next was missing. Thank you very much!

Comment: Personally, I don't like `DoubleNode *n = list->first`, you most probably want to pass in the first element of the linked list to `sum()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should fix your loop as follows.

```
double sum(DoubleList* list) {
    double sum = 0;
    for (DoubleNode *n = list->first; n != NULL; n = n->next) {
        sum += n->value;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

The sample code above assumes DoubleNode *has* an attribute named next and is of type DoubleNode*, that stores the pointer to the next element.

Answer (score 1):

You need to ensure you get the next element in your loop. I am guessing that the `next` pointer is `n->next`:

```
for (DoubleNode *n = list->first; n != NULL; n = n->next) {
    sum += n->value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
for (DoubleNode *n = list->first; n != NULL; n = next)
```

to

```
for (DoubleNode *n = list->first; n != NULL; n = n->next)
```